# Getting attributes from a unitialized class in Python

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.7

I'm trying to get all the attributes in a dict from a class without having an instance/initialization of it.

I tried different methods such dir(), **dict** but it doesn't work.

Example used:

```py
class Point:
      x: int
      y: int
      ids: Tuple[int]
```

I expect to get a dict with the attributes and types like:

```py
dict = {x: int, y: int, ids: Tuple[int]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since what you have are annotations, specifically **instance** annotations (as opposed to any defined values yet), you can see these using:

```
>>> Point.__annotations__
{'ids': typing.Tuple[int], 'x': <class 'int'>, 'y': <class 'int'>}
```

This is not the same as the actual class attributes. Maybe an example taken from [PEP-0526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations) would clarify the difference

```py
class BasicStarship:
    captain: str = 'Picard'               # instance variable with default
    damage: int                           # instance variable without default
    stats: ClassVar[Dict[str, int]] = {}  # class variable
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case one can also use [typing.get_type_hints()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) to get type hint information.

```
import typing

class BasicStarship:
    captain: str = 'Picard'               # instance variable with default
    damage: int                           # instance variable without default

print(typing.get_type_hints(BasicStarship))

# {'captain': <class 'str'>, 'damage': <class 'int'>}
```